# Looping javascript?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I am new to `js`, and `jquery`, and I am trying to fade in and out list items.
Im using the jQuery Cycle Plugin (with Transition Definitions).
Its working just fine, however I need this to loop. I am sure its something simple. However I cannot find a answer.:(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function InOut( elem )
{
  elem.delay()
 .fadeIn(400)
 .delay(5000)
 .fadeOut( 
           function(){ InOut( elem.next() ); }
         ) ;
}

$(function(){
$('#newsticker li').hide();
InOut( $('#newsticker li:first') );

});
</script>
```

Comment: i tried putting a for loop around it, but that breaks it...

Comment: Can you add your code to a jsFiddle? (with your HTML)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B2BDc/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

$('#newsticker li').hide();
InOut( $('#newsticker li:first') );

var lengthUl = $('#newsticker').children().length;
var i = 0
function InOut( elem )
{
     elem.delay().fadeIn(100).delay(100).fadeOut(function() {
            i++;
            InOut(elem.next());
            if(i == lengthUl){
                InOut( $('#newsticker li:first') );
                i = 0;
            }
        }   
    ) ;
}
});
```

Just use this as your `script`.

Added a `js Fiddle` Link too: Enjoy !

http://jsfiddle.net/shubham59/xmRqG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p id=elem>Here is some text</p>

<script>
var iv = setInterval(function() {$("#elem").fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400);},2000);
</script>
```

setInterval will continue executing until you ask it to stop. The function will fade in and out your element every couple of seconds. There's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2BDc/)

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the currently active list item is the last. If it is, go back to the first, like so:

```
if($("li:last").next().length === 0( {
    $("li:last").fadeOut();
    InOut( $("#newsticker li:first") );
}
```

I did something similar to allow cycling through a list of thumbnails as a [jsFiddle slideshow](http://jsfiddle.net/maddest_march_hare/8Fv4w/) mockup.

Comment: You may need to change the `if($("li:last")` to check for your specific, active element to make sure that the currently active element is the last in the list. In my jsFiddle you can see I've added a class to the active list item to work around this